# How to get Error Text from CustomTextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, textfield

I'm new to flutter. I wrote a custom textfield with errText. I want to retrive the error text from every Instance. errRetText is the class field to hold the string.  But I can't declare it as public to access from instance.
So I'm tring to get through getter. But I don't know how to call the getter from instance.
Similarly err is the method to generate error text from decoration. How to assign err value to errRetText?
How can I do it?

Following is the code of customtextfield. I marked my requirment. Pls help. Thanks in advance.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'DateHelper.dart';
import 'general.dart';

class CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final String hint;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final bool isPassword;
  final TextInputType keyboardType;
  final String textType; //Date , Number, NullText, ""
  final bool obscureText;
  final List<TextInputFormatter> inputFormatters;
  final value = "";
  final Function onChanged;
  final String? Function() err;
  static String errRetText = ""; // How to access this parameter from every instance, as public is not available???

  const CustomTextField({
    Key? key,
    required this.hint,
    required this.controller,
    required this.isPassword,
    this.keyboardType = TextInputType.text,
    required this.textType, //Date , Number, NullText ,""
    this.obscureText = false,
    required this.inputFormatters,
    required this.onChanged,
    required Function() onTap,
    required this.err,

    required InputDecoration decoration,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomTextField> createState() => _CustomTextFieldState();
}

class _CustomTextFieldState extends State<CustomTextField> {
  late bool valEdited;
  bool showPassword = false;

  String? get errText => CustomTextField.errRetText;    // How to access this getter from instance???

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    valEdited = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          controller: widget.controller,
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
          keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
          inputFormatters: widget.inputFormatters,
          obscureText: !showPassword && widget.isPassword,
          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
            setState(() {
              valEdited = true;
            });
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            suffixIcon: widget.isPassword
                ? IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.remove_red_eye,
                      color: showPassword ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() => showPassword = !showPassword);
                    },
                  )
                : IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.clear,
                      color: widget.controller.text.isEmpty
                          ? Colors.grey
                          : Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => widget.controller.clear()),
            border: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(10.0),
              ),
            ),
            filled: true,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800]),
            hintText: widget.hint,
            labelText: widget.hint,
            labelStyle:
                MaterialStateTextStyle.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
              final Color color = states.contains(MaterialState.error)
                  ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error
                  : Colors.orange;
              return TextStyle(color: color, letterSpacing: 1.3);
            }),
            fillColor: Colors.blue[200],
            errorText: err,  // How to assign this err value to errRetText
            
          ),
          
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 25,
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  String? get err {
    // at any time, we can get the text from _controller.value.text
    final text = widget.controller.value.text;
    // Note: you can do your own custom validation here
    // Move this logic this outside the widget for more testable code
    if (valEdited == true) {
      if (widget.textType == "Date") {
        if (text.isEmpty) {
          return 'Can\'t be empty';
        }
        if (!DateHelper.isValidDate(text)) {
          return 'Invalid Date';
        }
      }
      if (widget.textType == "Number") {
        if (text.isEmpty) {
          return 'Can\'t be empty';
        }
        if (!General.isNumeric(text)) {
          return 'Invalid Number';
        }
      }
      if (widget.textType == "NullText") {
        if (text.isEmpty) {
          return 'Can\'t be empty';
        }
      }
    }
    // return null if the text is valid
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any answer for this question?